# How to use count for multiple column counts in one run

Tags: r, dplyr, count

Usually, when I count a column in a data frame, I use the `count()` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl)
```

and

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(am)
```

and

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(gear)
```

etc...
Now I would like to count `cyl, am, gear` in one run.

**Note: I don't mean**

```
mtcars %>%
 count(cyl, am, gear)
```

My working approach so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(am) %>% 
bind_rows(mtcars %>% 
            count(cyl)) %>% 
  bind_rows(mtcars %>% 
              count(gear)) %>% 
pivot_longer(-n, 
             values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  unite("variable", c("name", "value")) %>% 
  relocate(variable, n)
```

```
  variable     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 am_0        19
2 am_1        13
3 cyl_4       11
4 cyl_6        7
5 cyl_8       14
6 gear_3      15
7 gear_4      12
8 gear_5       5
```

I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps pivot and count?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
select(mtcars, am, cyl, gear) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) |>
  count(name, value)
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   name  value     n
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1 am        0    19
# 2 am        1    13
# 3 cyl       4    11
# 4 cyl       6     7
# 5 cyl       8    14
# 6 gear      3    15
# 7 gear      4    12
# 8 gear      5     5
```

You can "clean up" the names if you want by pasting them together.

Comment: Okay, lol. I've definitely been away from coding for too long, or maybe my brain just hit a snag.

Comment: "Snag" is a common thing for me, glad I could help.